# Rename X-B3-TraceId headers in spring cloud sleuth

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have few services written in Node that are using "X-Request-Id" as the header to identify requests. I am now writing services in Java using spring-boot where I can use spring-cloud-sleuth to track traceId and spanId.

However, I would like to continue using the "X-Request-Id" as the request identifier across all of my services. Is there any way to rename the "X-B3-TraceId" header in spring-sleuth so that it sends the same header in HTTP requests and also uses the said header from incoming requests to set the traceId?

Answer (score 0):

You can propagate extra fields, see the [Propagation section of the Spring Cloud Sleuth docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/#propagating-extra-fields).

Comment: With propagation I'll have to support multiple headers - the previous one that all my Node services are using as well as the "X-B3-TraceId" that spring sleuth adds. Is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    propagation-keys: x-correlation-id
```